# Having issues accessing `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` from flask-marshmallow, though I have the latest version of flask-marshmallow installed

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I've tried various versions of flask-marshmallow, and have installed and uninstalled the latest version as well. As you can see below, I've also verified that I'm using the latest version which should have `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` but I'm not able to access it.

```
>>> import flask_marshmallow
>>> dir(flask_marshmallow)
['EXTENSION_NAME', 'LooseVersion', 'Marshmallow', 'Schema', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '__version_info__', '__warningregistry__', '_attach_fields', 'base_fields', 'compat', 'exceptions', 'fields', 'flask_sqlalchemy', 'has_sqla', 'pprint', 'schema', 'warnings']
>>> flask_marshmallow.__version__
'0.12.0'
>>> flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow()
<flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow object at 0x10300de48>
>>> flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow().SQLAlchemyAutoSchema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Marshmallow' object has no attribute 'SQLAlchemyAutoSchema'
```

I'm out of ideas on what could be causing this. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this link and tried all the solution suggested there to see if that would fix your issue?
https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-marshmallow/issues/56

Comment: Yeah, I'd gone through those suggested fixes.  What ended up working for me was upgrading marshmallow-sqlalchemy to version 0.23.0.

Comment: Would you share your Flask and  Flask_Marshmallow versions? I am trying with 2.2.2 and  0.12.0. In my case, they are working with Marshmallow_SQLAlchemy 0.23.0

Answer (score 1):

This does not apply to you, but I have got the same error while tinkering on a test project with barebone SQLAlchemy instead of Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Installing Flask-SQLAlchemy solved the error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing 'marshmallow-sqlalchemy'

Comment: any idea why that helped?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Didn't look into it, I figure something gets overridden by marshmallow-sqlalchemy and dependencies for flask-marshmallow aren't configured quite right. It might be that doing this is optional and you only 'need' marshmallow-sqlalchemy if you want to use SQLAlchemyAutoSchema.